# C# I'm trying to create a web user control with custom classes, and I am getting a Object not set to an instance of an Object Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I hope you can help me with this.  I am creating an internal webforms asp.net site to display a list of internally used documents in different categories.

I decided to create a custom document class to put in a list to hold the documents, and then a custom web user control to display the documents wherever they want them on the site.

The documents class is in a general class file in my App_Code folder.

cabinet.cs

```
public class Document
{
    private string _Url;
    private string _Title;
    public Document(string URL, string Title)
    {
        _Url = URL;
        _Title = Title;
    }

    public string URL
    {
        get { return _Url; }
        set { _Url = value; }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set { _Title = value; }
    }
}
```

This code works just fine.  Then in my user control I create a list of type document and initiate it in Page_Load().  Then I created a public method to add new documents to the list.

DocDisplay.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class DocDisplay : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private List<Document> _DocList;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _DocList = new List<Document>();
    }

    public void Add(string URL, string Title)
    {
        _DocList.Add(new Document(URL, Title));
    }

    public void WriteDocuments()
    {
        foreach (Document doc in _DocList)
        {
            Response.Write($"<span class='document'><a href='{doc.URL}'>{doc.Title}</a></span>");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the error in the add method.  It says that my object is not to an instance of an object.  But I do that in Page_Load.

index.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pageDocs.Add("index.aspx", "Hello World!");
    pageDocs.Add("index.aspx", "Red Rum");
    pageDocs.Add("index.aspx", "Lorum Ipsum");
}
```

I have registered my user control in my index page.

```
<%@ Register Src="~/DocDisplay.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="DocDisplay" %>

<uc:DocDisplay ID="pageDocs" runat="server" />
```

So I am not exactly sure why I am getting that error.  As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with my code.  If you could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Where is `pageDocs` instantiated?

Comment: I updated the post.  I add the control in my html with <uc:DocDisplay ID="pageDocs" runat="server">  as far as I know, that should be sufficient.

Comment: I commented out the add commands and added the breakpoint where you said.  It gets called after Page_Load on the index page.  Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events get fired starting from the root of control hierarchy and end at the leaf nodes.  `Index.Page_Load` is being called before `DocDisplay.Page_Load` has an opportunity to instantiate the list.

The `_DocList` field needs a value before it can be used by anything, so initialization needs to happen as early as possible.  This is accomplished very easily with a field initializer.  Declare and assign it all at once:

```cs
private List<Document> _DocList = new List<Document>();
```

When the `Index` class instantiates its child controls early in the page life cycle, `_DocList` will immediately have an object reference.

It's tempting to say, "Page_Init will be called sooner; I'll do it there."  This may work at first, but if you do *any* dynamic control loading, you'll soon find out that it's a balancing act.  A dynamically loaded control has to play event catch-up, so its `Init` event can be fired after statically loaded controls have started firing `Load` events.  It's important to use each event for its purpose, and not for its timing, and use constructors (and field initializers) to initialize non-control class state.